# Joining 3 SQL Querys with Pivot/Unpivot in them

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a tables named `MachineSweepQuestions` , `MachineSweepAnswers` , `MachineSweetComments`, I need to join all 3 of these tables using what i think are `Pivots` as displayed in my code so they can share an outcome via a few parameters. Below are pictures of the code with a image of the returned results and a Idea of what my end goal should but , all these tables share the column name `AreaID` and `LastChecked` ( These will be the parameters passed.

Question Query:

```
Select AreaID, Questions From (Select AreaID, Question1,
Question2,
Question3,
Question4,
Question5,
Question6,
Question7,
Question8,
Question9,
Question10,
Question11,
Question12,
Question13,
Question14
From MachineSweepQuestions) x
UNPIVOT
(
Questions
For QuestionID in (Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6,Question7,Question8,Question9,Question10,Question11,Question12,Question13,Question14)
) unpiv Where AreaID='8'
```

[image: Questions]

Answers Query:

```
 Select Answer,LastChecked From (select AreaID,Answer1,
 Answer2,
 Answer3,
 Answer4,
 Answer5,
 Answer6,
 Answer7,
 Answer8,
 Answer9,
 Answer10,
 Answer11,
 Answer12,
 Answer13,
 Answer14,
 LastChecked
 From MachineSweepAnswers) x 
 UNPIVOT
 (
 Answer
 For AnswerID
in(Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4,Answer5,Answer6,Answer7,Answer8,Answer9,Answer10,Answer11,Answer12,Answer13,Answer14)
 ) unpiv Where AreaID = '8' AND LastChecked = '2014-04-01'
```

[image]

The Hopeful Final Outcome:

[image: FinalOutcome]

so my question is , Does anyone know how to Join these Pivots with my comments query to achieve the outcome of below as I've tried many ways and searched for answers in the hopes of guidance yet have come to a dead end, any help is welcome. ( My paint skills make De Vinci cry! ) ...

EDIT!:! I missed comments off , the SQL query is `Select CommentsBox,Lastchecked From MachineSweepComments Where AreaID='8' And LastChecked='2014-04-01'`

Comment: could you build SQL Fiddle for your data?

Comment: No , I'm using SQL-Server mate , Fiddle is of no use.

Comment: Do you even know what SQL Fiddle is?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ If you build your data there we can help you much faster

Comment: I don't know what it is. :/ but yes Mikka I will..

Comment: SQL Fiddle seems a little out of my depth changing syntax etc, surely there is another way.. it just seems like a join on Area ID passed with @AreaID ( Query string based parameter in the data souce ) and a @Laschecked(Also Query string parameter ) would fix this but it's the joining involving pivots i do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try at this :

```
Select * from (Select AreaID, Questions From (Select AreaID, Question1,
Question2,
Question3,
Question4,
Question5, 
Question6,
Question7, 
Question8, 
Question9, 
Question10,
Question11,
Question12,
Question13,
Question14 From
MachineSweepQuestions) x UNPIVOT ( Questions For QuestionID in
   (Question1,
    Question2, 
    Question3, 
    Question4, 
    Question5,
    Question6,
    Question7,
    Question8,
    Question9,
    Question10,
    Question11,
    Question12,
    Question13,
    Question14)
   ) unpiv Where AreaID=@AreaId) AS tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          (Select Answer,
                  LastChecked, AreaId From (select AreaID,
                                           Answer1,
                                           Answer2,
                                           Answer3,
                                           Answer4,
                                           Answer5,
                                           Answer6,
                                           Answer7,
                                           Answer8,
                                           Answer9,
                                           Answer10,
                                           Answer11,
                                           Answer12,
                                           Answer13,
                                           Answer14,
                                           LastChecked
                                                 From MachineSweepAnswers) x 
                                             UNPIVOT
                                                 (
                                                 Answer
                                                 For AnswerID
                                                 in(Answer1,
                                                 Answer2,
                                                 Answer3,
                                                 Answer4,
                                                 Answer5,
                                                 Answer6,
                                                 Answer7,
                                                 Answer8,
                                                 Answer9,
                                                 Answer10,
                                                 Answer11,
                                                 Answer12,
                                                 Answer13,
                                                 Answer14)
                                                 ) unpiv Where AreaID = @AreaId 
                                                 AND LastChecked = '2014-04-01') 
                        AS tbl2 ON tbl1.AreaId=tbl2.AreaId
              LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select CommentsBox,
                                 Lastchecked,
                                 AreaId From MachineSweepComments 
                                             Where AreaID=@AreaId 
                                             OR AreaId IS NULL
                                             And LastChecked='2014-04-01') 
                         AS tbl3 ON tbl1.AreaId=tbl3.AreaId
```

If this doesn't work then feel free to talk to me